# What is this symbol that looks like a resistor with an arrow pointing at it?

Tags: identification, schematics, symbol

I am in first year of Engineering school and I was given an assignment which contains this circuit which drives pressure sensors in a pitot tube :

[image]

For training, I am trying to reproduce it using the gEDA free software, but I came accross those little beasts named A1 and A2 I can't reproduce.

What are they ?

[as an aside, does anyone have an idea about which piece of software could have produced this image ? ]

Comment: Potentiometers.

Comment: why would there be potentiometers in such a circuit ??? :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

A1 and A2 are potentiometers.  (This diagram uses the European notation.)

This diagram could have been drawn in a general-purpose (not specialized for electrical engineering) diagramming tool such as MS Visio. It was not drawn in Altium, or Eagle, or OrCAD.

**update:**

> why would there be potentiometers in such a circuit ??? :(

Potentiometers are there to make adjustments.  A1 acts as a adjustable voltage divider (together with R16); it scales the output of OpAmp III.  A2 acts as an adjustable voltage divider; it scales the output of the OpAmp IV.

[As an aside, I wouldn't design this circuit the way they did.  I would use instrumentation amplifiers (InAmp). I wold guess that the original designers had a goal that the circuit could be made with components that are cheap and available the world over.]

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a circuit diagram from France. The notation CAPT1 and CAPT2 means  Capteur or Sensor. AFF means Affiche or Display. POT A1 appears to be calibrating or balancing the output of the 2 sensors.  POT A2 appears to adjust the output level going into the display unit. This of course is an educated guess as it has been a while since I worked with stuff like this.